# AJAX запросы - очередность

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

У нас есть серверное приложение, к которому посылается AJAX запрос после загрузки страницы. После того как ответ на первый запрос пришел, скрипт продолжает посылать AJAX запросы до того момента как в ответе будет флаг (что больше данных нет).

Теперь вопрос - у AJAX есть какие-либо механизмы для того чтобы, если пользователь перезагружает страницу, и шлется AJAX запрос(ы) ему/ей не пришел бы ответ из предыдущего запроса, заместив собой корректный (в тех случаях когда сервер долго обрабатывал бы этот запрос)? Я спрашиваю именно про встроенные механизмы - заметил что в GET параметрах шлется _ (underscore) и это похоже на идентификатор запроса, который можно использовать, отсылая обратно и сопоставляя с исходным по получению. Есть ли что-то еще?

Нужно учесть что при запросе приложением совершается работа, длившаяся несколько секунд, поэтому и есть подозрение что такой сценарий и возникает.

Сценарий описанного:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По идее сначала загружается страница, а затем запускается жаваскрипт. Поэтому не должно быть такого, что приходят запросы с предыдущей страницы. Если вдруг такое обнаружите - это будет баг. А вы запросы AJAX посылаете методом GET? Может лучше делать это методом POST, чтобы не было проблем с кешированием на уровне браузера или прокси.

Comment: @Ivan Bolnikh, да, запрос шлется через GET, и дело в том что вероятно это и есть баг, но на уровне приложения, которое продолжает работу и выдает результат, не зная о том что страница, запросившая работу, уже не та.

Comment: Перейти на POST нет возможности? Если нет, то добавляйте к запросу уникальный идентификатор страницы и возвращайте его в ответе. А уже на странице его проверяйте.

Comment: Я не думаю что это может решить проблему так как она не связана с кэшированием AJAX ответов, только если в POST есть механизм, описанный выше, для предотвращения получения "неправильного" ответа - но попробую это использовать...

Comment: Так оно и получилось - добавляем уникальный идентификатор при загрузке страницы и проверяем его в ответе. И да, так и получилось что приходили ответы с других страниц, поэтому такой механизм помог нам преодолеть эту проблему.